# HTTParty + Webmock | Invalid url inside specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, webmock

When running requests with `disable_rails_query_string_format` with such query params:

```
query: {selected_ids: [1,2,3]}
```

It works fine when running the code in the app, but when running specs, the url become truncated and only last element of the array is taken, so that url become `selected_ids=3` instead of `selected_ids=1&selected_ids=2&selected_ids=3`.

Don't know if that matter, but additionally we use Webmock to stub requests inside specs.

Maybe someone ran the same issue and know what may cause it?

**Update, code abstraction**

Let's say, here's a service called Client:

```
class Client
  include HTTParty

  SOME_ENDPOINT = 'http://someurl.com/some-endpoint'.freeze

  def do_get(options = {})
    self.class.disable_rails_query_string_format
    self.class.get(SOME_ENDPOINT, options)
  end
end
```

And at some point it gets executed, let's say, by some action performed by controller, which delegates execution to resource and resource executes that service:

```
# Somewhere in resource
Client.new.do_get(selected_ids: [1, 2, 3])
```

When the code above gets executed in non-test environment, `Client` makes a correct call to `http://someurl.com/some-endpoint?selected_ids=1&selected_ids=2&selected_ids=3`

But under specs, when doing the same thing without `stub_request`, Webmock error got raised indicating the unmocked url, which is incorrect: `http://someurl.com/some-endpoint?selected_ids=3`

Generally, spec is not doing some extra steps and looks like standard RSpec specs:

```
describe Client
  subject { Client.new.do_get(selected_ids: [1, 2, 3]) }

  it
    subject
  end
end

# -> Webmock error - unregistered request to 
# http://someurl.com/some-endpoint?selected_ids=3,
# but it should be to 
# http://someurl.com/some-endpoint?selected_ids=1&selected_ids=2&selected_ids=3
```

Comment: Can you add the rspec code that's not working?

Comment: also a part of controller responsible for handling input params will help as well